# Testing change in ratios

Tags: regression, anova, inference, least-squares, ratio

I do not know how to perform this statistical test. I have a proportion of a bodily liquid substance, and I am interested in the ratio with respect to another. For instance, ratio of water (20l) and plasma (4l) = 5.

There is a placebo and treatment group, so I wanna test if both ratios suffer from the same change (so in placebo group, ratio can increase by 10%, but in treatment group ratio can increase 15%).

How can I test that both ratio's increase are not equal? I thought on ANOVA, but it assumes normality of data (and ratios are usually not normally distributed).

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59145/linear-regression-with-a-dependent-variable-that-is-a-ratio answer your question? It appears to. If it does not, please edit your question to say why.  (Also, ANOVA does not require normal data; it assumes normal errors).

Comment: Hello Peter, I have read the related posts, but I am more confused than before. Does that mean that if I make this new regression and obtain a coeficient not equal to 0 for Bx, inference is not valid? And this issue fixes when using a log transformation? I didn't really understand the answer

Comment: OK then I guess it doesn't answer your quetion.