# Ratio variable as a dependent variable and a percentage as a independent

Tags: regression, linear, ratio, dependent-variable

I am doing a unit-level linkage analysis using performance indicators (at unit level) from an audit to predict the percentage of a successful indicator. Basically, I am trying to see if the ratio health professional:patient can predict the percentage of patients that will respond favourably to a specific process. I do not have any individual data only unit-level since I am analysing the national performance of hospitals. So, I used a linear regression but I am having troubling interpreting the results. So if my beta=-0.5, does it mean that the model predicts that per each unit decrease in ratio professional:patient, the percentage of the successful will increase 50%?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58664/ratios-in-regression-aka-questions-on-kronmal/410465#410465