# Dealing with Ratios in Linear Regression

Tags: regression, linear-model, linear

I am studying the relationship between X and Y using linear models. Both are composed of a left and right scalar value, and I'm interested in the relationship between both the totals and ratios for each one. My first thought is to create two linear models:

y<sub>ratio</sub> = y<sub>right</sub>/y<sub>left</sub>
y<sub>total</sub> = y<sub>right</sub>+y<sub>left</sub>
x<sub>ratio</sub> = x<sub>right</sub>/x<sub>left</sub>
x<sub>total</sub> = x<sub>right</sub>+x<sub>left</sub>

y<sub>ratio</sub> = B<sub>0</sub>+
B<sub>1</sub>x<sub>left</sub>+
B<sub>2</sub>x<sub>right</sub>+
B<sub>3</sub>x<sub>ratio</sub>

y<sub>total</sub> = B<sub>0</sub>+
B<sub>1</sub>x<sub>left</sub>+
B<sub>2</sub>x<sub>right</sub>+
B<sub>3</sub>x<sub>ratio</sub>

Is this sensible, or is there a better systematic approach? I'm having trouble searching for this, but it seems like a reasonably common problem. My thought is that while my models are over parameterized in the sense that while the ratio can be expressed in terms of the left/right values, that can't be achieved with a weighted sum, and it is reasonably plausible (for instance) that y<sub>total</sub> is best predicted by x<sub>ratio</sub>

Comment: You should tell us more about the context. There are some similar questions, start with https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58664/ratios-in-regression-aka-questions-on-kronmal

Comment: Please edit the question to say more about the nature of your X and Y variables and how the "left" and "right" components of each are determined. In particular, are all of the values necessarily greater than 0? Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.